# Node.js module.export vs export caching

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

After going through node docs, I understand [caching](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) a little bit. Using
`module.exports{constant_1, constant_2}` will cache its assigned value, so everytime when we call require('') it will get the cached value instead of creating a new one.

```
example_1.js
const test = 'testValue';
module.export = {test};

example_2.js
const cachedValue = require('../example_1.js');
console.log(cachedValue);
```

But does the caching happen when we use the below syntax?
export `{constant_1, constant_2}` statement as well?

```
example_1.js
const test = 'testValue';
export {test};

example_2.js
import {test} from "example_1";
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import {test} from "example_1";
```

should be

```
import {test} from "./example_1.js";
```

like the CommonJS example, but otherwise the caching behavior is similar for ES modules. The [node docs for ESM files](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) for instance states

> ES modules are resolved and cached as URLs. This means that files containing special characters such as # and ? need to be escaped.

So as long as the an `./example_1.js` and another one somewhere else resolve to the same URL, it will be cached as the same module.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation, so technically speaking both are same only difference is new es6 template.

Comment: Caching-wise yes they are pretty much the same. ES6 imports are potentially more capable, like you might be able to eventually import a module from a full URL, which Deno for instance supports, where you cannot do that with `require`.